# I want to use NRF24L01 transceiver with raspberry pi but some GPIO pins are already occupied by 3.5 inch display how do i connect transceiver

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, display

26 GPIO pins are already used by 3.5 inch display some of these occupied pins are needed to connect  transceiver. I am using NRF24L01 for wireless communication between raspberryPi and arduino

can i use breadboard and connect pins parallelly.